# Negating Alternation In Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, regex-negation

I can use "Alternation" in a regular expression to match any occurance of "cat" or "dog" thusly:

```
(cat|dog)
```

Is it possible to NEGATE this alternation, and match anything that is NOT "cat" or "dog"?

If so, how?

For Example:

Let's say I'm trying to match END OF SENTENCE in English, in an approximate way.

To Wit:

```
(\.)(\s+[A-Z][^.]|\s*?$)
```

With the following paragraph:

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  Once upon a time Dr. Sanches, Mr. Parsons and Gov. Mason went to the store.  Hello World.

I incorrectly find "end of sentence" at Dr., Mr., and Gov.

(I'm testing using http://regexpal.com/ in case you want to see what I'm seeing with the above example)

Since this is incorrect, I would like to say something like:

```
!(Dr\.|Mr\.|Gov\.)(\.)(\s+[A-Z][^.]|\s*?$)
```

Of course, this isn't working, which is why I seek help.

I also tried !/(Dr.|Mr.|Gov.)/, and !~ which were no help whatsoever.

How can I avoid matches for "Dr.", "Mr." and "Gov.", etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You would normally do this using negative lookbehind `(?<!…)`, but JavaScript's regex flavor does not support this. Instead, you will have to filter the matches after the fact to discard those you don't want.

Comment: I'm not using Javascript, but ActionScript.  Are you aware if Actionscript shares this limitation?

Comment: It does. It looks like the only thing added by the [ActionScript regex syntax](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000112.html) is named capture groups of the form `(P<name>…)`.

Answer (score 0):

In language like Perl/awk, there's the `!~` operator

`$string !~ /(cat|dog)/`

In Actionscript, you can just use NOT operator `!` to negate a match.  See [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/RegExp.html) for reference. Also [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) for regex flavors comparison

Comment: That syntax almost definitely won't work in AS, but the concept does. It's run a regex, which returns true if it matches. Then just not that relationship (which is done with a ! in AS as well as many other languages).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot rely on the NOT operator in the language using the regular expressions... I need to know how to accomplish the NOT operator WITHIN the regular expression itself.  I hope my edit of the question makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
!/(cat|dog)/
```

EDIT: You should've included the programming language on your question. Its Actionscript right? I'm not an actionscript coder but AFAIK its done like this:

```
var pattern2:RegExp = !/(cat|dog)/;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the slashes?

Comment: Forward slashes are a standard way declare a regex in some languages (javascript, perl, probably others).

Comment: I appologize for the lack of clarity in the original post.  I've made some changes to make my needs more clear.  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

(?!NotThisStuff) is what you want, otherwise known as a negative lookahead group.

Unfortunately, it will not work as you intend. **/(?!Dr\.)(\.)/** will still return the periods that belong to "Dr. Sanches" because of the second grouping. The Regex parser will say to itself, "Yep, this '.' isn't 'Dr.'" **/((?!Dr).)/** won't work either, though I believe it should.

And what's more, you'll end up looking through all the sentence "ends" anyway. Actionscript doesn't have a "match all," only a match first. You have to set the global flag (or add g to the end of your regex) and call exec until your result object is null.

```
var string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. Once upon a time Dr. Sanches, Mr. Parsons and Gov. Mason went to the store. Hello World.';

var regx:RegExp = /(?!Dr\.)(\.)/g;
var result:Object = regx.exec(string);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // paranoia
  if (result == null || result.index == 0) break; // again: paranoia
  trace(result.index, result);
  result = regx.exec(string);
}

// trace results:    
//43 .,.
//64 .,.
//77 .,.
//94 .,.
//119 .,.
//132 .,.
```